# IF in sql to choose which values to select

Tags: sql, if-statement, select

I am trying to use an IF or CASE statement in sql to choose when to select a value in a column. Essentially I have some data in a table like so:

[image]

My goal is to see which *items* are ordered multiple weeks in a row by the same *customer*. I have 1 month of dates, but I can do 7 separate queries with 1 query for each day of the week. I'm trying to do something like:

```
Select item, date, customer, truck

    If customer, item combo appears in multiple weeks
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how I can do this!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? This is important to know. Then, are you taking about a certain date range, e.g. calendar week 20 to 24, or just about a number of consecutive weeks (e.g. 5 adjacent weeks, no matter whether this year or five years ago)? Or do you want a combination of both, e.g. five consecutive weeks in 2021?

Comment: Then, do you want one line per customer and item or do you want to show one line per per customer and item and week or do you want to show the customer and item with all their orders in those weeks?

Comment: I am using Snowflake, and I have years worth of data but have been limiting it to 1 month in the WHERE clause while working on it so that it runs faster. I would love to also show a number of consecutive weeks column if that's possible. I am currently using the solution provided by Gordon which solves the specific question I was asking in this post, but if you know how to to create a "number of consecutive weeks" column as well that would be much appreciated!  I want to see the data one line per customer and item, and I am ordering by item ID then by customer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have at most one row per week per customer and item (as in the sample data), you can use `lead()` and `lag()`.  The following assumes that you mean exactly 7 days apart:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(orderdate) over (partition by customer, itemid order by orderdate) as prev_orderdate,
             lead(orderdate) over (partition by customer, itemid order by orderdate) as next_orderdate
      from t
     ) t
where prev_orderdate = orderdate - interval '7 day' or
      next_order_date = orderdate + interval '7 day';
```

Note that date/time functionality is highly database dependent, so you might have to adjust for your database functions.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is '7 day' just a value that SQL understands can be applied to data with the date type? Or does the interval keyword somehow make it readable when run?

Comment: @laurat801 . . . `interval '7 day'` is a SQL standard format for an interval constant.  As the answer explains, you may need to adjust the syntax to fit whatever database you are using.